# Beta testing app without using Play Store

Tags: facebook

I am interested to test Facebook Messenger beta version. In this case, [Facebook suggests](https://code.facebook.com/posts/361241240681298/introducing-the-facebook-messenger-for-android-beta-testing-program/)

> 1. Join the Facebook Messenger for Android Beta Testers Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/messenger-for-android-beta-testers
> 2. Allow beta downloads by clicking "Become a Tester" in the Play Store (you need to join the Google Group before becoming a tester)
> 3. Download Facebook Messenger from the Play Store to update your app
> 4. Turn on automatic updates, as the beta version of Facebook Messenger for Android will be updated multiple times per week

But it's not applicable to my case since my phones (running YunOS 2.9.0) don't come with preinstalled Google apps, like Play Store.

So, is there anyway I can get the beta version of Messenger?

Comment: XDA is a popular option for beta, haven't checked for your need

Answer (score 1):

No, not officially, although you may be able to find the APK on a collection site like http://www.apkmirror.com

Developers often use Google Play to manage beta distribution because it gives them some semblance of control over the distribution and upgrade of the application. Often beta applications are not available outside of this distribution channel.

Comment: Thanks.
apkmirror.com exist facebook messenger latest beta version.
But problem is when i download this, it says parse error.

Comment: @andio This may be due to your phone's Android version: if an APK (the app installer) has been pulled from a Lollipop (and up) phone, it won't work on KitKat and lower devices. What's your Android version?